# What am i doing wrong with flexbox trying to align these images?

Tags: css, flexbox

So I am trying to align images one next to another with display flex but they're not working, tried a lot of things but none of them helped

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="image">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Each `.image` element is set to `width: 100%`. This means they'll take up the full width of the container, which is set (by default) to `flex-direction: row`, and which you have set to `flex-wrap: wrap`. Therefore, you can expect your flex items to stack individually in a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove

```
width: 100%;
```

from your `.image` styles.

**Working Example:**

```css
.container {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

<div class="image">        
<img src="photo.jpg">
</div>

<div class="image">        
<img src="photo.jpg">
</div>

<div class="image">        
<img src="photo.jpg">
</div>

<div class="image">        
<img src="photo.jpg">
</div>

</div>
```

---

## Update:

Do you want a single row of 4 images? If so, you'll need to give each image a `width` or a `flex-basis` of equal to or less than `25%` of the `.container`.

Otherwise an image will be assumed to have a width corresponding to its original size.

You can achieve this by inserting `.image {flex: 0 1 25%;}` into your CSS:

```
.container {
display: flex;
width: 100%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.image {
flex: 0 1 25%;
margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: What are you seeing in your setup that's different from the output displayed in the code snippet output box above?

Comment: Well, the image doesn t shrink to fit the screen, it just goes and i need to scroll to see the end of the image. Maybe it's because it's the same image ? but i don' t think so

Comment: Do you want a single row of 4 images? If so, you'll need to give each image a `width` or a `flex-basis` of equal to or less than `25%` of the `.container`. Otherwise an image will be assumed to have a width corresponding to its original size. Try `.image {flex: 0 1 25%;}`

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer above. When you have enough reputation, you can upvote the answer too. Thank you.